# Does gmail use SPF or DMARC when sending messages outside of gmail?

Tags: email, gmail, spf, dmarc

I can't seem to find any record of SPF or DMARC in the original messages coming from gmail to my mail server.

Does gmail use SPF or DMARC when sending messages outside of gmail?

Comment: What are you expecting to see, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPF and DMARC are not used for sending, they are used at the receiving side. It is up to the sender to publish a policy via DNS and it is up to the recipient to check the incoming mail against the senders policy. Both steps are optional.

GMail has both SPF and DMARC policies which can be seen by doing a DNS TXT lookup:

```
$ dig txt gmail.com
...
gmail.com.         91 IN TXT "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.google.com"

$ dig txt _dmarc.gmail.com
...
_dmarc.gmail.com.  95 IN TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none; sp=quarantine; rua=mailto:mailauth-reports@google.com"
```